# Get dictionary contains in list if key and value exists

Tags: python, list, if-statement, dictionary, conditional-statements

How to get complete dictionary data inside lists. but first I need to check them if key and value is exists and paired.

```
test = [{'a': 'hello'  , 'b': 'world', 'c': 1},
        {'a': 'crawler', 'b': 'space', 'c': 5},
        {'a': 'jhon'   , 'b': 'doe'  , 'c': 8}]
```

when I try to make it conditional like this

```
if any((d['c'] is 8) for d in test):
```

the value is True or False, But I want the result be an dictionary like

```
{'a': 'jhon', 'b': 'doe', 'c': 8}
```

same as if I do

```
if any((d['a'] is 'crawler') for d in test):
```

the results is:

```
{'a': 'crawler', 'b': 'space', 'c': 5}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is` tests for identity, not for equality which means it compares the memory address not the values those variables are storing. So it is very likely it might return `False` for same values. You should use `==` instead to check for equality.

As for your question, you can use `filter` or list comprehensions over `any`:

```
>>> [dct for dct in data if dct["a"] == "crawler"]
>>> filter(lambda dct: dct["a"] == "crawler", data)
```

The result is a list containing the matched dictionaries. You can get the `[0]`th element if you think it contains only one item.

Answer (score 2):

Use comprehension:

```
data = [{'a': 'hello'  , 'b': 'world', 'c': 1},
        {'a': 'crawler', 'b': 'space', 'c': 5},
        {'a': 'jhon'   , 'b': 'doe'  , 'c': 8}]

print([d for d in data if d["c"] == 8])
# [{'c': 8, 'a': 'jhon', 'b': 'doe'}]
```

Comment: Please change `is` to `==` and this answer will be perfect. `is` is used for identity check

Comment: I sorta just copied that form the question, did the edit.

Comment: @SSj.Luffy I know, just thought it was worth noting. Feel free to add it to your answer so `OP` can be aware of this